# how do I make my quantity data work in my add to cart component in React?

Tags: reactjs

So I have my shop, cart and add to cart all sorted but I want to include a quantity element where the user cannot add to cart more than is in stock. Ive added a quanity item to my json data source and I thought that would fix it but it hasnt. What else do I need to do to enable this function? Thanks in advance. Below is my add to cart component, an exert of my JSON file with product data in and my cart

add to cart

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Link, useNavigate  }
from "react-router-dom";
import Cart from '../Cart';
import productsData  from '../data/products.json';

export default function addToCart({product, products, cart, setCart}) {


const addToCart = product => {

let newCart = [...cart];
let itemInCart = newCart.find(
  (item) => product.name === item.name
);
if (itemInCart) {
  itemInCart.quantity++;
} else {
  itemInCart = {
    ...product,
    quantity: 1,
  };
  newCart.push(itemInCart);
}
setCart(newCart);
 };

return (
<>
<button onClick={() => addToCart(product)}>
  Add to Cart
 </button>

    </>
    );
     }
```

my JSON file

```
{
"productsData" :
[
 {
        "id": "0004",
        "category": "FASHION",
        "name": "Ladies Small BOY London Distressed Acid Wash Blue Midi Denim Skirt",
        "cost": 50,
        "quantity": 2,
        "image":"images/Boy.jpeg",
        "image2": "",
        "image3":"",
        "description": "Ladies Small BOY London Distressed Acid Wash Blue Midi Denim 
        Skirt. BOY London sizes run small. This skirt is size 8/10 even though the 
        label says large. Condition is New with tags."

        },

      {   "id": "0005",
          "category": "FOOTWEAR",
          "name": "Ladies Size 8 / 41 Black Real Suede Jeffrey Campbell Platform Open 
           Toe Sandals",
          "cost": 60,
          "quantity": 1,
          "image":"images/Campbell.jpeg",
          "image2": "",
          "image3":"",
          "description": "Ladies UK Size 8 European size 41 black real suede Jeffrey 
          Campbell high platform open-toe sandals with adjustable strap. The sandals 
           are in good condition as theyve only worn outside a few times. The heel 
           and platform is made from wood so the sandals are sturdy but relatively 
           lightweight. "

        },
        ]}
```

and my cart

```
import React, { useState }from 'react';
import productsData  from './data/products.json';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Link, useParams } from "react- 
router-dom";

export default function Cart({ cart, setCart }) {


const [products, setProducts] = useState(productsData.productsData);

const getTotalSum = () => {
return cart.reduce(
  (sum, { cost, quantity }) => sum + cost * quantity,
  0
 );
 };

const clearCart = () => {
setCart([]);
 };

const setQuantity = (product, amount) => {
const newCart = [...cart];
newCart.find(
  (item) => item.name === product.name
).quantity = amount;
setCart(newCart);
 };

const removeFromCart = (productToRemove) => {
setCart(
  cart.filter((product) => product !== productToRemove)
  );
 };

return (
<>
  <h1>Cart</h1>
    {cart.length > 0 && (
      <button onClick={clearCart}>Clear Cart</button>
    )}
    <div className="products">
      {cart.map((product, idx) => (
        <div className="product" key={idx}>
          <h3>{product.name}</h3>
          <h4> £ {product.cost}</h4>
          <input
            value={product.quantity}
            onChange={(e) =>
              setQuantity(
                product,
                parseInt(e.target.value)
              )
            }
          />
          <img src={product.image} alt={product.name} />
          <button onClick={() => removeFromCart(product)}>
            Remove
          </button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>

    <div>Total Cost: £{getTotalSum()}</div>

   </>
   );
   }
```

Comment: don't you update products data once you add any item to cart ? You need to update that as well right !?

Comment: erm, no idea..sorry